# What is the inradius of a $5$-$6$-$9$ triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

> What is the radius of the circle inscribed in a triangle with side lengths $5$, $6$, and $9$?
>
> **(Ignore that the image says the triangle is inscribed in a circle.)**
>
> [image]

I'm not sure where to start and, as well as hints/an answer, advice on solving such geometry questions (apart from the usual, add in a few lines and see what happens!) would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Your figure doesn't match your description. a triangle is inscribed in a circle means all the vertices of the triangle lies on the the circle. (refs: see wiki entry of [inscribed figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_figure))

Comment: you seem to be correct!- the diagram is correct so let's go with that

Comment: Let $I$ be the incenter and $r$ be the inradius, draw 3 rays from $I$ to the vertices and cut your triangle into 3 smaller triangles. what is the area of these triangles in terms or $r$ and the side? Can you use it to deduce $r$ from the area and perimeter of original triangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Note that the lines joining the angles to the incentre divide the triangle into three smaller triangles, with bases $a,\,b$ and $c$ respectively and each with height $r$. The sum of areas of these three triangles, hence the area $A$ of the original triangle, is $$A=\frac{ar}{2} + \frac{br}{2} + \frac{cr}{2}$$
We get the inradius as
$$r=\frac{A}{s}\quad...(s=\frac{a+b+c}{2})$$